# PHPUnit: Testdependencies with test from parentclass

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

So, I've got a little problem with my Unittests. I wrote some basisclasses for different Testcases and I want to uses some prepared test-methods.

i.e.

```
class ModelTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testCreateInstance() { ... }
}

class UserModelTest extends ModelTestCase {
  /**
   * (at)depends testCreateInstance
   */
  public funcion testWhatever($model) { ...}
}
```

Is there any trick to use it as I want or must I really write every test in every class?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you really want to do, your code sample is way too vague to tell that.

One option for you is to create your own `setup()` method in `ModelTestCase` (don't forget to call `parent::setUp()`) and do some initialization in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test only the derived model tests, but not the base class itself, you can declare it as abstract:

```
abstract class ModelTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testCreateInstance() { ... }
}
```

This worked for me.